# How to activate a Python virtual environment and execute a script at the same time?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to load automatically my Python virtual environment and execute a python query at the same time in Powershell but I am not getting any luck at it. This is the code I have:

```
# my_testing_file.py

# Activate the virtual environment
import os
script_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
activate_this_file = os.path.join(script_directory, 'C:\Temp\Development\Python_scripts\env\Scripts\activate_this.py')

# Start executing the main code
import pypyodbc
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook

def main():
    cursor = initiate_connection_db()
    unposted_hours_results = retrieve_results_query(cursor)
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

All the code is in 1 single file and basically I want to do in Powershell `python my_testing_file.py` so it loads the virtual environment and executes the rest of the code.

When this code gets executed from Powershell, a command prompt appears for a few seconds and then it shuts down and the rest of the code never gets executed. Any help for fixing this code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using a postactivate script through your virtualenv/virtualenvwrapper?

Comment: How can you use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @dfundako indicated, a post-activate script could have done the trick to activate the virtual environment and execute the script all at once, however, I found another alternative which I believe it is not the best but it performed what I needed to achieve. I had to pack the python script and its libraries in an .exe file so once a user clicks on it, the program executes the desired task.

Inside of my virtual environment, I executed this file called setup.py to build my_testing_file.py to an .exe:

```
# Python 3.6.7
# The cx_Freeze library did the trick to pack all the libraries and the script. 
# Put down all the scripts that your 

import sys, os
import openpyxl
import cx_Freeze
import my_testing_file.py
from subprocess import call

base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = "Win32GUI"

# my_testing_file is the main script that executes my desired task.
executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("my_testing_file.py", base=base)]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "Testing Deploy",
options = {"build_exe":
           {"packages":
            ["openpyxl", "subprocess"]
            }
           },
version = "0.01",
description = " Testing executable alternative",
executables = executables
)
```

I believe something similar could have been done with Docker as well but I lack the required knowledge to achieve the same goal. Feel free to improve this answer or put the code for the Docker alternative or the aforementioned post-activate script.